# next-seo library meta tags are not showing in page source but I can see in inspect document

Tags: next.js, seo, vercel

I am trying to add seo tags to my nextjs e-commerce application. I am using [next-seo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-seo) library to add meta tags and schema markup. There is default seo for _app.js and NextSeo component for other pages. When I try to see meta tags on the page source, it doesnt show up, but I can see them in the inspect. Seo plugin works fine but it doesn't work on the server side rendering.

```
const App = ({Component, pageProps: {session, ...pageProps}}) => {
        return (
            <SessionProvider session={session}>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
                        <>
                            <DefaultSeo
                                title='Chokqu Online Çocuk Giyim Alışveriş Mağazası'
                                titleTemplate='%s | Chokqu Online Çocuk Giyim Alışveriş Mağazası'
                                defaultTitle='Chokqu Online Çocuk Giyim Alışveriş Mağazası'
                                description='Çocuk giyim, bebek kıyafetleri ve yeni yürüyen kıyafetleri için uygun fiyatlarla alışveriş yapın.'
                                languageAlternates={[
                                    {
                                        hrefLang: 'tr-TR',
                                        href: 'https://www.chokqu.com',
                                    },
                                    {
                                        hrefLang: 'en-US',
                                        href: 'https://en.chokqu.com',
                                    }
                                ]}
                                themeColor='#ffffff'
                                canonical='https://www.chokqu.com'
                                openGraph={{
                                    type: 'website',
                                    locale: 'tr_TR',
                                    url: 'https://www.chokqu.com',
                                    title: 'Chokqu Online Çocuk Giyim Alışveriş Mağazası - Yeni Yürüyen ve Bebek Kıyafetleri',
                                    description: 'Chokqu Online Çocuk Giyim Alışveriş Mağazası, geniş bir çocuk giyim ve bebek kıyafetleri koleksiyonu sunar. Online alışverişin keyfini çıkarın ve yeni yürüyen kıyafetleri arasından seçim yapın.',
                                    images: [
                                        {
                                            url: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/resimler/chokqu-social-media-buyuk.jpg`, // Paylaşım için görsel URL
                                            width: 1200,
                                            height: 630,
                                            alt: 'Chokqu Online Çocuk Giyim Alışveriş Mağazası',
                                        },
                                        {
                                            url: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/resimler/chokqu-social-media-kucuk.jpg`,
                                            width: 800,
                                            height: 600,
                                            alt: 'Chokqu Online Çocuk Giyim Alışveriş Mağazası',
                                        },
                                    ],
                                    site_name: 'Chokqu Online Çocuk Giyim Alışveriş Mağazası',
                                }}
                                twitter={{
                                    handle: '@chokqu',
                                    site: '@chokqu',
                                    cardType: 'summary_large_image',
                                }}
    
                            />
                            <Head>
                                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
                                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
                                <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
                                <meta name="twitter:site" content="@chokqu"/>
                                <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@chokqu"/>
                                <meta name="twitter:title" content="Chokqu Online Çocuk Giyim Alışveriş Mağazası"/>
                                <meta
                                    name="twitter:description"
                                    content="Çocuk giyim, bebek kıyafetleri ve yeni yürüyen kıyafetleri için uygun fiyatlarla alışveriş yapın."
                                />
                                <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://www.chokqu.com/og-image.jpg"/>
    
                            </Head>
                            <Component {...pageProps} />
                        </>
                    </PersistGate>
                </Provider>
            </SessionProvider>
        );
    };
```

This is my app.js. There is default meta tags here.

```
export default function Home() {
    return (
        <FrontendLayout>
            <NextSeo
                title='Anasayfa | Chokqu Online Çocuk Giyim Alışveriş Mağazası'
                description='Çocuk giyim, bebek kıyafetleri ve yeni yürüyen kıyafetleri için uygun fiyatlarla alışveriş yapın.'
                openGraph={{
                    url: 'https://www.chokqu.com',
                    title: 'Chokqu Online Çocuk Giyim Alışveriş Mağazası',
                    description: 'Çocuk giyim, bebek kıyafetleri ve yeni yürüyen kıyafetleri için uygun fiyatlarla alışveriş yapın.',
                    images: [
                        {
                            url: 'https://www.chokqu.com/og-image.jpg',
                            width: 1200,
                            height: 630,
                            alt: 'Chokqu Online Çocuk Giyim Alışveriş Mağazası',
                        },
                        {
                            url: 'https://www.chokqu.com/og-image.jpg',
                            width: 800,
                            height: 600,
                            alt: 'Chokqu Online Çocuk Giyim Alışveriş Mağazası',
                        },
                    ]
                }}
                twitter={{
                    handle: '@chokqu',
                    site: '@chokqu',
                    cardType: 'summary_large_image',
                }}
            />
            <main className="">b
                <SocialProfileJsonLd
                    type="Organization"
                    name="Chokqu Online Çocuk Giyim Alışveriş Mağazası"
                    url="https://www.chokqu.com"
                    sameAs={[
                        'https://www.facebook.com/chokqu',
                        'https://twitter.com/chokqu',
                        'https://www.instagram.com/chokqu',
                    ]}
                />
            </main>
        </FrontendLayout>
    )
}
```

this is my home page.

When I check frontend inspect I can see all meta tags but I cannot see them in the page source.